# SQL Finding multiple values difficulty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate the correct SQL for a project.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
DateTime          |  EmpID |  Function  |  Location
--------------------------------------------------
1/23/2015 2:00PM  |  123   |  1         |  1
1/23/2015 2:10PM  |  123   |  2         |  1
1/23/2015 2:20PM  |  123   |  1         |  2
1/23/2015 2:40PM  |  123   |  2         |  2
1/24/2015 2:00PM  |  321   |  1         |  2
1/24/2015 2:15PM  |  321   |  2         |  2
1/24/2015 2:30PM  |  321   |  1         |  3
```

I need to pull a count of all records where functionid = 1 and location MUST EQUAL both 1 and 2. So the first row and the third row would be returned and considered a count of 1.

Hopefully I'm making sense with this. Basically I need to know how many times an employee was at two locations. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: group by having count(distinct location) >= 2

Answer (score 0):

Group by EmpId and count locations.

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable T1 
 WHERE Function = 1 AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM MyTable T2 
                    WHERE T1.EmpId = T2.EmpId AND
                          T1.Function = T2.Function AND
                          T2.Location NOT IN (1, 2))
GROUP BY EmpId
HAVING Count(DISTINCT Location) > 1
```

Comment: If Location Count is 3, this is considerd valid, but the OP only wants 1 and 2, but not 3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmpID , COUNT(*) total, COUNT (CASE WHEN Location = 1 THEN 1 END) was_in_1,COUNT (CASE WHEN Location = 2 THEN 1 END) was_in_2
FROM table
WHERE Function = 1
GROUP BY EmpID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Location = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = MAX(CASE WHEN Location = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

but if you would like to know if the employee was in any 2 locations then jarlh gave the right comment

```
group by EmpID
having count(distinct location) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.EmpID, COUNT(*) 
FROM YOURTABLENAME A 
INNER JOIN YOURTABLENAME B 
ON A.EmpID= B.EmpID
WHERE  A.Location = 1 and B.Location = 2 
and A.Function = B.Function and A.Function = 1
GROUP BY A.EmpID
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested it but think this will work

```
SELECT EmpID, COUNT(EmpID) AS NumOfTimes
From [Table Name] 
WHERE FunctionID = 1 AND (Location = 1 OR Location = 2)
GROUP BY EmpID 
HAVING NumOfTimes = 2
```

Comment: will not work if employee was only in location 1 for few times and had never been in 2